# Displaying @datetime in UTC format from Elasticsearch database rollup using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, datetime-format, rollup

We are using Elasticsearch rollups of metricbeat data using Kibana.  Instead of @datetime we would like to see the date in UTC.  I cannot find an option to do this in Kibana.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I tried to modify the JSON configuration directly but Kibana will not allow it.

This is the JSON configuration file for the rollup:

```js
{
  "config": {
    "id": "cpu_daily_rollup",
    "index_pattern": "metricbeat-*",
    "rollup_index": "cpu_daily",
    "cron": "0 0 0 * * ?",
    "groups": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "fixed_interval": "24h",
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "delay": "30m",
        "time_zone": "UTC"
      },
      "histogram": {
        "interval": 5,
        "fields": [
          "system.cpu.total.pct"
        ]
      },
      "terms": {
        "fields": [
          "system.cpu.total.pct",
          "fields.oss.id",
          "system.cpu.cores"
        ]
      }
    },
    "metrics": [
      {
        "field": "system.cpu.total.pct",
        "metrics": [
          "avg",
          "max",
          "value_count",
          "sum",
          "min"
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "metrics": [
          "value_count"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "timeout": "20s",
    "page_size": 1000
  },
  "status": {
    "job_state": "started",
    "current_position": {
      "@timestamp.date_histogram": 1564963200000,
      "fields.oss.id.terms": "5a4fe62140a7078a7930ceac",
      "system.cpu.cores.terms": 2,
      "system.cpu.total.pct.histogram": 0,
      "system.cpu.total.pct.terms": 1.948
    },
    "upgraded_doc_id": true
  },
  "stats": {
    "pages_processed": 17,
    "documents_processed": 5424850,
    "rollups_indexed": 15490,
    "trigger_count": 1,
    "index_time_in_ms": 4725,
    "index_total": 16,
    "index_failures": 0,
    "search_time_in_ms": 47329,
    "search_total": 17,
    "search_failures": 0
  }
}
```

We just need to convert the field "@timestamp.date_histogram.timestamp" in UTC format.  I.e., we want '07-23-2019T19:34:00.000000' rather than '1563910440000'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put the date field you want as a max metric value, fortunately elasticsearch will recognize it as a date. Something you can do too, is to reindex the data to another index with a ingest pipeline that fix your field.

This is what i mean:

```
{
    "field": "@timestamp",
    "metrics": [
      "max"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I see.  I'll try to do that.  Thank you for the response!